# PowerShell EWS SendAndSaveCopy() in specific folder

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for EWS to be able to store a mail that is sent in a specific folder, not just in the 'Sent Items' folder.

**Mailbox structure:**

```
Mailbox@mail.com
- Inbox
- ----- PowerShell
- ----- ---------- Mail OUT
```

How can I have EWS save the sent mail in `Inbox\PowerShell\Mail OUT` ?

I've tried the following without success:

```
$Message.SendAndSaveCopy('WellKnownFolderName.Inbox.PowerShell.Mail OUT')
$Message.SendAndSaveCopy('WellKnownFolderName.Inbox\PowerShell\Mail OUT')
$Message.Send()
$Message.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::'Inbox\PowerShell\Mail OUT')
```

The examples on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634269(v=exchg.80).aspx) are only valid for C#.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You will need to find the `FolderID` of the folder you're trying to save to. You can't use the `WellKnownFolderName` because the folder you're trying to save in is not a member of the enum

Comment: Thank you arco444, I figured out a way to retrieve the `FolderID` as you mentioned. What is the correct syntax to use it with `$Message.SendAndSaveCopy()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as arco444 pointed out, we need to retrieve the `FolderId` number. After that a simle `Send` and `Save` will do the trick.

For anyone interested:

```
Function Find-FolderID {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Path,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [String]$Mailbox,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Object]$Service
    )

    $FolderId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$Mailbox)
    $TargetFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($Service,$FolderId)  

    $Array = $Path.Split('\')

    for ($i=1; $i -lt $Array.Length; $i++) {
            $FolderView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1) 
            $SearchFilter = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName,$Array[$i]) 
            $Results = $service.FindFolders($TargetFolder.Id,$SearchFilter,$FolderView) 
            if ($Results.TotalCount -gt 0) { 
                foreach($R in $Results.Folders) { 
                    $TargetFolder = $R                
                } 
            } 
            else { 
                throw "Folder '$Path' not found in mailbox '$Mailbox'"
            }     
    }  
    $TargetFolder.Id
}

Find-FolderId -Path '\Inbox\PowerShell\Expiring users OUT' -Mailbox 'Mailbox@mail.com' -Service $EWS

$Message.Send()
$Message.Save($FolderID)
```

Comment: Does this really work? I get `This operation can't be performed because this service object already has an ID. To update this service object, use the Update() method instead.`